# flink 1.9.1 java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/FlinkKafkaConsumer

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am now using flink 1.9.1 when I run in itellij，it is good. But when i package it in a shade jar, it show this error, i am confused and i cant get some useful information:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/kafka/FlinkKafkaConsumer
        at com.baidu.cloud.flink.hotel.HotelStatistics.main(HotelStatistics.java:40)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:576)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:438)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.ClusterClient.run(ClusterClient.java:274)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:746)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.runProgram(CliFrontend.java:273)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:205)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseParameters(CliFrontend.java:1010)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$main$10(CliFrontend.java:1083)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:30)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1083)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumer
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
        ... 15 more
```

Comment: Please show how you create the shade jar

Comment: I have already know the reason, I packaged the shade jar with excludes the "<exclude>org.apache.flink:*</exclude>", thanks for guiding me~